# Pushing data from one component to a another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-router

So I am having a problem with payment Component. Basically I want when I press on the link it pushes (ClassG imageG and PriceG) into the Payment Component where I can style them again I have tried something but it is giving me the straight information(Arayys) when I click on the Link. That is not exactly what I want. I would like some help if possible. Thanks in Advance

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../data.json";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function G() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black '>
{data.filter(d =>
  d.classG &&
  d.imageG &&
  d.priceG)
  .map((postData) => {
        return (
          <div className='bg-black'  key={postData.id} >
            <div className='bg-black '>            
              <img
                alt=""
                className="w-full object-contain "
                src={postData.imageG}
              ></img>
              <h1 className=" ml-24 mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-2 mlg:static text-5xl mlg:text-2xl text-blue-400 
               absolute top-48">
                {postData.classG}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="text-lg  mlg:mb-2 mlg:ml-6  mlg:mt-2 mlg:static font-bold text-green-800 
               font-mono ml-24 top-64  absolute" >
                {postData.priceG}
              </h1>
              <Link
                to={`/payment/${postData.id}`}
                className="py-1 px-2  mlg:ml-6 mlg:mt-14 mlg:static text-black-600 h-8  ml-24  top-72 bg- 
                white w-32 text-center text-gray-red
                rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-600 absolute" 
              >
                Buy Now
              </Link>
              <div id='New' className="flex flex-col mt-40 justify-center border-white text-center items- 
                center bg-black" >
              <h1 className='tracking-tighter mb-20 text-white text-base md:text-6xl'>What's new in 
                2021</h1>  
              <h1 className=' md:p-4 md:w-2/4 font-sans mb-16 text-white '>{postData.newG} </h1>                  
              </div>   
               </div>
                 </div>
           )
            }
    export default G

json file
[
{
    "id":1,
    "classG":"G-Class",
    "imageG":"./ModImages/Gclass.jpg",
    "priceG":"Starting at $154,900"
    "newE": "some text"

},
]

Payment Component
import React from "react";
import data from "./Models/data.json";
function Payment(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const {
    match: {
    params: { dataId }
    }
  } = props;
  const item = data.find(({ id }) => id === Number(dataId));
  return (
    <div className="ml-20">        
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Payment;

App Component
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './assets/main.css'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='' >     
      <div>
          <Router>       
             <Header />     
          <Switch>        
            <Route path="/a">
              <A />
            </Route>
             <Route path="/payment/:dataId" component={Payment}>
             </Route>
           </Switch>  
           </Router>
            </div>
               </div>

  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite understanding your request, but you don't push any data anywhere, you're importing the JSON object into your `Payment` component and finding a matching element by id. Are you trying to instead send this data via the `Link`?

Comment: @Drew Reese Yes I wanna send the data where I can style the img price and class at the new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send the specific product data you can use the route state of the routing transition.

[Link - to: object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/payment/${postData.id}`,
    state: {
      postData,
    },
  }}
  className="..." 
>
```

The route state can be accessed on the receiving route's component on the [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object. Components rendered by a `Route`'s `render`, `component`, or `children` prop receive all the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
function Payment(props) {
  const {
    location: {
      state: {
        postData, // <-- access route state from location.state
      },
    },
    match: {
      params: { dataId }
    },
  } = props;

  const {
    classG,
    imageG,
    priceG,
    // ... any other postData object properties
  } = postData;
  
  return (
    <div className="ml-20">        
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(postData, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am wanting to do, it is passing the data but its passing the whole data.I want to pass image price and class to the payment so I would need to filter it somehow. And when I get to the payment page by clicking on the link I want to style to the image classs and price

Comment: @Tequila No, it passes a single `postData` object that was mapped in the linking component `G`. The data object has the `imageG`, `priceG`, and `classG` properties you mentioned, what needs to be filtered from here? You have the data now so it's up to you how you want to render it in your `Payment` component. Can you explain more in your question how you are trying to render this data differently than just JSON.stringifying it?

Comment: @ Drew Reese https://paste.pics/391c8bacf25732f10431c499090c8c34 its dispaying all the info I have more object in the array or I would say other classes. Maybe I am using the json stringify wrong or Maybe I dont even need it.

Comment: @Tequila Ah, I added a bit more code show how to destructure the properties you want from the passed object. From there you can do just about anything since they are just variables. Like I said though, if you can explain a bit better what you want to do with this data differently I can refine my answer.

Comment: .Have you seen the link how can I style img class and price in the payment page

Comment: @Tequila I looked at the link, it's the stringyfied JSON. Sorry, it's still quite unclear to me what you are asking to style. Are you asking how to render the class, image, and price properties into DOM elements like `img`, `div`, and `p`, like a "real" web page?

Comment: Yes I am asking that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226799/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-tequila).

Comment: It would work If I had only 1 object in the json file and onlt one Component but I have 10 more.Lets add another Component for example named A content is we are gonna say is the same as in the Component G but the images price and class are not(img p and h1)
So when I press the LInk in component A i want to only render that (img price and class) from the Component A into the payment. When I press the Link in the Component G i want to render only that img price and class from Component G.I hope you understood